# How To Validate RequestHeader For RestAPI Controller Endpoint

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, bean-validation, request-headers

I've written a controller class with an endpoint that accepts a header as part of its request

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("<mapping-path>")
public class MyController {
...
@GetMapping("<path-to-the-endpoint>")
public MyObject getMyObject(@RequestHeader("headerName") String headerName) {
    //do something with the header here
}
...
}
```

The endpoint is working fine but I'd like to test its behavior when a header with a null value is supplied.  I'd also like to code the `getMyObject` method in such a way that it prevents null values from being passed into the header and will return a warning saying that the header field cannot be empty.  I've tried to test this using an integration test with a `MockMvc` `get()` on the endpoint but if I grant a null value to the header as part of that get request the test fails as it says "values cannot be empty".  Is it possible to use JSR-303 validation methods here?  i.e. `@Valid` and `@NotNull`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the parametrized request header should work for you.

Try declaring your method like this.

```
@GetMapping("<path-to-the-endpoint>")
public MyObject getMyObject(@RequestHeader(value="headerName") String headerName) {
    //do something with the header here
}
```

To test this, you can add a header in your MockMvc.

```
post("/your end point").header("headerName", "userId")
```